# Augmented Lagrangian methods for nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization

Let $f(\cdot):\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},h(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be nonlinear functions. Consider the nonlinear optimization problem $$\begin{matrix}\min_x f(x)\\ \text{s.t. }h(x)=0\end{matrix}$$
The method of multipliers is based on the following algorithm:

1. Select $\lambda_0>0\in \mathbb{R^m}$
2. At step $i$: Compute $x_i=\min_x f(x)+\lambda_i^T h(x_i)+\frac{c}{2}||h(x)||^2$
3. At step $i$: Compute $\lambda_{i+1}=\lambda_i+ch(x_i)$
4. Go back to 2.

For a large enough $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the method converges to a local optimum $x^\star$ of $f(x)$ subject to $h(x)=0$ with associated Lagrange multiplier $\lambda^\star$.

My question is about step 2, which is another nonlinear optimization problem. From a practical point of view, it seems to me that we can only obtain *local* solutions to step 2, e.g. with gradient descent. However, the theory is based on the fact that $x_i$ is the global optimum of the augmented Lagrangian function. Can we still ensure convergence of the algorithm to a local minimum of $f(x)$ subject to $h(x)=0$, if at every step 2 we compute a *local* minimum of the augmented Lagrangian? Am I misenterpreting the theory?  Thanks!

Comment: The result you are saying about "for large enough c" I am not sure if it holds. If you know such result in such generality, I suggest you link it here. The convergence of augmented Lagrangian method are associated to sequential optimality conditions, and not to local convergence. As far I know, the local convergence of Augmented Lagrangian schemes can only be guaranteed when assumed a second order optimality condition, or based on  a "error bound property".

Answer (score 1):

Using the lagrangian or augmented lagrangian you should know that the solutions for the stationary points of

$$
\nabla L(x,\lambda)  = 0
$$

are located at $L's$ saddle points or

$$
L(x^*,\lambda)\le L(x^*,\lambda^*)\le L(x,\lambda)
$$

where $x^*, \lambda^*$ is a solution for $\nabla L = 0$. Once you got  $x^*, \lambda^*$ you should check the kind of solution $x^*$ offers, using the bordered hessian of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$. This method appears to be more direct but it can converge to unexpected points.

The proposed sequential method is more reliable to get the solution to the minimization problem associated to $f(x), h(x)$